# Get a MySQL stored array in string format and convert to array in JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I have an array stored in a mysql table, like this:

```
[3,5,6,7,8]
```

When I select it, encode it as JSON in PHP and then parse it into a javascript object, instead of it becoming an array, it just becomes a string "[3,5,6,7,8]". I know it's not possible to store it as an array in a single field, so.. what could I do so it will convert properly to an array instead of string?

My current code:

```
test = JSON.parse('[{"id":43,"incidence":"[0,3,6,7]"}]')
```

I could solve it removing the " on the string, but mysql returns it with the string, php encodes with the quotes and javascript parses with quotes. So basically, is there a way to remove it in this process?

Comment: can you show your code? how are you encoding it and how are you parsing it?

Comment: after your initial parsing, have you tried this: `JSON.parse(test[0].incidence)` ?

Comment: In your database results, will you always have only 1 row result? or will it sometimes be more than one? I ask this because currently you have an array of arrays which makes for an extra iteration down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies on how you are constructing your array prior turning it into JSON. Since you are retrieving these results from the database, I am assuming you are constructing a multidimensional array that may look something like this:

```
$results = array(
    array(
        "id" => 43,
        "incidence" => "[0,3,6,7]"
    )
);
```

Because `incidence` is a string, it is giving you those errors when using it in JS. To solve you need to turn that string into an array. Now, since you might have more than one result (being that these are database results) you need to iterate through the result array and turn that string into an array like this:

```
foreach ($results as &$row) { // <-- notice the & symbol (Passing by reference)
    $no_brackets = trim($row["incidence"], '[]');//if you stored your array as comma delimited value, you would not need this.
    $row["incidence"] = explode(',', $no_brackets);
}
```

Lastly, use `json_encode` and pass it to JS.

---

**Final Result:**

```
<?php
foreach ($results as &$row) {
    $no_brackets = trim($row["incidence"], '[]');
    $row["incidence"] = explode(',', $no_brackets);
}
$json = json_encode($results);
?>

<script>
    var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $json ?>');
    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little fiddling to get this to work.

Try this

```
<?php

$string = '[3,5,6,7,8]';
$t = str_replace(array('[',']'), '', $string);
$array = explode(',', $t);
echo json_encode($array);
```

The result is

```
["3","5","6","7","8"]
```